Why is Marked2 not showing image in preview?
My picture shows in Obsidian, but Marked2 doesn't see it.

The picture is in the same directory as the .md file.
I tried using a full path, but that didn't fix it.
I downloaded Obsidian to see if it would recognize the image, and it did.
I used "toggle source view" in Marked2 and it shows as html.
The file on disk is as below.

Pasted directly from the file, which was originally created in vim:
![book](a_wizard_of_earthsea.jpg "title")
Ged was the greatest sorcerer in Earthsea, but ...

